# PHP - Google Recaptcha - file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, openssl, recaptcha

I am using the Google ReCaptcha library in my PHP application. It has been working reliably for quite a while now. However, today, I started receiving errors related to the library.

```
    *[05-Apr-2018 09:19:03 America/Chicago] Severity: 2,Message: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed,File: E:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\google\recaptcha\src\ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post.php,Line: 68
[05-Apr-2018 09:19:04 America/Chicago] Severity: 2,Message: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto,File: E:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\google\recaptcha\src\ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post.php,Line: 68
[05-Apr-2018 09:19:04 America/Chicago] Severity: 2,Message: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream: operation failed,File: E:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\google\recaptcha\src\ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post.php,Line: 68*
```

I did not make any changes to my application. The issue just started suddenly and (from my perspective) without logical explanation.

For reference, here is the Post.php from Google's library (not authored by me).

```
public function submit(RequestParameters $params)
{
    /**
     * PHP 5.6.0 changed the way you specify the peer name for SSL context options.
     * Using "CN_name" will still work, but it will raise deprecated errors.
     */
    $peer_key = version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0', '<') ? 'CN_name' : 'peer_name';
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $params->toQueryString(),
            // Force the peer to validate (not needed in 5.6.0+, but still works)
            'verify_peer' => true,
            // Force the peer validation to use www.google.com
            $peer_key => 'www.google.com',
        ),
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    return file_get_contents(self::SITE_VERIFY_URL, false, $context);
}
```

The last line is "68". I am using PHP 7.1. with `OpenSSL 1.0.2k 26 Jan 2017`. I am calling the library as follows:

```
    // validate ReCaptcha

$response = null;
$reCaptcha = new  \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(RECAPTCHA_SECRET);
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $response = $reCaptcha->verify(
           $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"],  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
    );
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. The application is hosted on IIS and Windows Server.

Comment: I too have all started having this issue as of today... I think it may be something to do with the Symantec debacle

Answer (score 2):

Mikail G.'s answer is nearly correct, you do need to access it over CURL. I think something has been changed to actually prevent your current (and mine) from working as I have seen several posts about it all from recent days.

Use this instead:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'secret' => $secretKey,
        'response' => $captcha,
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    ],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($output);
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I did not try it out personally, it seems as it might be a good workaround for someone else experiencing the issue. Personally, my resolution actually involved manually downloading the cacert.pem file and then setting the `openssl.cafile` path in my `php.ini` file. I am not positive why it suddenly stopped working though.

Comment: I have had the same issue with it just stopping all of a sudden

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $stream_opts = [
    "ssl" => [
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ]
    ];  
$secret = '6Le__FoUAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXoQtXhJfdZi92ZPHaAj';
$gRecaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; 
$remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$gRecaptchaResponse&remoteip=$remoteIp";
    $response=file_get_contents($url,false, stream_context_create($stream_opts));
    $result = json_decode($response);
    if ($result->success) 
    {

        header("location: index.php");
    }
    else
    echo 'Captcha verification failed.
}
?>
```

No need to include the autoload.php file. Just include the file below just before closing tag 
`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>` and before the submit button add the following code `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le__FoUAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXoQtXhJfdZi92ZPHaAj"></div>`

Copy and paste all the folders of recaptcha v2 in home directory of your site. This will 100% work in localhost without ssl. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the issue you need to call the google api with "http" , or use a diffrent way to make request such as curl , here the function to do so :

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url, $data (array)) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        json_encode($data));



    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);



    return $server_output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, the website that call the reCaptcha library (Google's servers) is not actually accessed over https.

Comment: Google does not provide https ? , have you tried it ? coz it is not possible that google does not have https option

Comment: Sorry, but what I meant was my server/website is not accessed over https. However, according to the error logs, it is attempting to access Google over https (specifically https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify). Also, if it helps, I have an ASP.NET MVC application on the same server that also uses Google's reCaptcha service, and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: the issue is with SSL certificate , try to call the google api with http request , or try to request the api with curl , coz it seems like when you make the request you can't read their SSL certificate

Comment: this may help :  function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try [Step by Step guide to integrate reCpatcha](https://www.paperpencilwriteup.com/step-by-step-guide-to-integrate-google-recaptcha-2-0.html)

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question really. Also helpful if you write the answer because this the page linked to could be removed at anytime.

Comment: @tim.baker - don't worry it won't be removed and if it does for some reason it's always on cache.